# python find last in string

Tags: python, string, find

I'm looking for a simple method of identifying the last position of a string inside another string ... for instance. If I had: `file = C:\Users\User\Desktop\go.py`
and I wanted to crop this so that `file = go.py`

Normally I would have to run `C:\Users\User\Desktop\go.py` through a loop + find statement, and Evey time it encountered a `\` it would ask ... is the the last `\` in the string? ... Once I found the last `\` I would then `file = file[last\:len(file)]`
I'm curious to know if there is a faster neater way to do this.. preferably without a loop.
Something like file = `[file('\',`**last**`):len(file)]`
If there is nothing like what I've shown above ... then can we place the loop inside the `[:]` somehow. Something like `file = [for i in ...:len(file)]`

thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is only about file paths, you can use [`os.path.basename`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename(file)
'go.py'
```

Or if you are not running the code on Windows, you have to use `ntpath` instead of `os.path`.

Comment: When dealing w/ filepaths this is the best solution. But just for the record: There is also a `rfind` method in python: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind

Comment: As I said: `rfind` doesn't look so good with filepaths, the `os.path` solution is the best.

Answer (score 5):

You could split the string into a list then get the last index of the list.

Sample:

```
>>> file = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\go.py'
>>> print(file.split('\\')[-1])
go.py
```

Comment: The other answers are great .. but I like yours because it has broader application ... not only in path strings.

Comment: Thanks man :) it's a nice, clean option that doesn't require adding dependencies. I think if you had to deal with the os not only in this situation then adding an extra import would be the better option.

Comment: You shouldn't split the string and then take only one part of it. This is both slower and more confusing. A much simpler method is `x[x.rfind('\\')+1:]`

BTW, you might want to avoid the name `file` for your variable name because it will shadow the built in file object.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Felix on that file paths should be handled using `os.path.basename`. However, you might want to have a look at the built in string function [`rpartition`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition).

```
>>> file = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\go.py'
>>> before, separator, after = file.rpartition('\\')
>>> before
'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop'
>>> separator
'\\'
>>> after
'go.py'
```

There's also the [`rfind`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) function which gives you the last index of a substring.

```
>>> file.rfind('\\')
21
```

I realize that I'm a bit late to the party, but since this is one of the top results when searching for e.g. "find last in str python" on Google, I think it might help someone to add this information.

Answer (score 2):

For the general purpose case (as the OP said they like the generalisation of the split solution)...... try the `rfind(str)` function.

```
"myproject-version2.4.5.customext.zip".rfind(".")
```

edit: apologies, I hadn't realized how old this thread was... :-/

Answer (score 0):

For pathname manipulations you want to be using [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html).

For this specific problem you want to use the [`os.path.basename(path)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) function which will return the last component of a path, or an empty string if the path ends in a slash (ie. the path of a folder rather than a file).

```
import os.path

print os.path.basename("C:\Users\User\Desktop\go.py")
```

Gives:

```
go.py
```